# Symfony2 formbuilder HTML field

Tags: forms, symfony, customization, formbuilder

I am creating a form with formbuilder in symfony2. In this form I want to put some custom HTML, but I don't want to template the whole thing, eg. I want to use     `{{ form_widget(form) }}`. Is it possible to put some custom html between the fields ?

@EDIT: to make it more clear

```
$builder
  ->add('description')
  ->add('thisIsMyHTMLField', '<p>Render this HTML</p>') //This is just custom html
  ->add('talentName')
  ->add('keywords')
  ->add('differentiation')
```

Comment: So, put it another way, you want to customize the html rendered by the form_widget(form) method in your template, right?

Comment: not really it's more like having a custom field I guess, that just renders HTML I put in and not a form field. But creating a custom form field for this seems like such overkill.

Comment: But why don't you just add html code between your fields when rendering them separately. It's a  much cleaner solution.
You can also use additional fields that are not mapped to your form object.

Comment: For reusability reasons I would like not to start rendering them seperately

Answer (score 0):

One possibile method (that save you from overwrite default behaviour of `{{ form_widget() }}`) is to do something like

```
{% for fields in form %}
 {% if fields.vars.name != '_token' %}
  {% if fields.vars.errors|length %} <div="errors">
  {% else %} <div class="{{ cycle(["even","odds"], loop.index) }}">
  {% endif %}
  {{ form_label(fields) }}
  {{ form_widget(fields) }}
  {{ form_errors(fields) }}
  </div>
 {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

I understand your drive to extract forms entirely into form types, but in this case you are looking for specific layout control. Templates are where layout should be done!

Within your template, simply break up the form into it's parts.

While writing:
`{{ form_widget(my_form) }}`
feels clean, theres absolutely nothing preventing you from controlling the layout entirely:

`{{ form_row(my_form.an_item) }}`

`<div>Custom HTML</div>`

`{{ form_row(my_form.another_item) }}`